# jQuery Validation redirects to homepage after validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I have implemented the Jquery Validation Plugin (http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/) into my website that uses javascript to slide divs. The plugin works fine and it validates the form, but after redirectuing to the thank you div, then it redirects back to the homepage and I don't know why. You can view the website here: http://webdevkit.org/admin/SlowFire/index.php# and you cand find the contact form under the about section.

The code that holds the validation function looks like this and the form validation has been implemented allright:

```
function animate() {
var currentPageI = -1;
var pages = [
    $('div.dhome'),
    $('div.dabout'),
    $('div.dcontact'),
    $('div.dportraits'),
    $('div.dpregnancy'),
    $('div.dbabies-newborn'),
    $('div.dbabies-3-6'),
    $('div.dbabies-6-24'),
    $('div.dkids'),
    $('div.dfamily'),
    $('div.dall-about-me'),
    $('div.dcouples'),
    $('div.dpets'),
    $('div.dthe-experience'),
    $('div.dfinishing-touches'),
    $('div.dthank-you'),
];
var viewsWidth = 1300; 
var showPage = function(index){
    if(index === currentPageI){return;}
    var currentPage = pages[currentPageI];
    if(currentPage){
        currentPage.stop().animate({left: -viewsWidth})
    }
    var nextPage = pages[index];
    nextPage
        .stop()
        .css({left: viewsWidth + Math.max(0,(($(window).width() - 980)/2))})
        .animate({left: Math.max(0,(($(window).width() - 980)/2))})
    currentPageI = index;
}; 
var center = function(index){
    if(index === currentPageI){return;}
    var currPage = pages[currentPageI];
    if(currPage){
    currPage
        .stop()
        .css({left: viewsWidth + Math.max(0,(($(window).width() - 980)/2))})
        .animate({left: Math.max(0,(($(window).width() - 980)/2))})
    }
    var nextPage2 = pages[index];
    nextPage2
        .stop()
        .css({left: viewsWidth + Math.max(0,(($(window).width() - 980)/2))})
        .animate({left: Math.max(0,(($(window).width() - 980)/2))})
    currentPageI = index;
};

// show default page
showPage(0);
$('a.dhome').click(showPage.bind(null, 0));
$('a.dabout').click(showPage.bind(null, 1));
$('a.dcontact').click(showPage.bind(null, 2));
$('a.dportraits').click(showPage.bind(null, 3));
$('a.dpregnancy').click(showPage.bind(null, 4));
$('a.dbabies-newborn').click(showPage.bind(null, 5));
$('a.dbabies-3-6').click(showPage.bind(null, 6));
$('a.dbabies-6-24').click(showPage.bind(null, 7));
$('a.dkids').click(showPage.bind(null, 8));
$('a.dfamily').click(showPage.bind(null, 9));
$('a.dall-about-me').click(showPage.bind(null, 10));
$('a.dcouples').click(showPage.bind(null, 11));
$('a.dpets').click(showPage.bind(null, 12));
$('a.dthe-experience').click(showPage.bind(null, 13));
$('a.dfinishing-touches').click(showPage.bind(null, 14));
$("#contactform").validate({
submitHandler: function(form) {
showPage(15);
form.submit();
}
});
```

I don't know why it redirect back to the site's root after validation.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem with event.preventDefault();

```
$("#contactform").validate({
submitHandler: function(form) {
showPage(15);
event.preventDefault();
$form.submit();
```

}